# Add the array objects field data in to single object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I getting this data into my response

```
var data=[ { id: 9,
    ticketId: 9,
    member: { id: 3, email: 'ganeshpandi@gmail.com' } },
  { id: 10,
    ticketId: 9,
    member: { id: 4, email: 'braveganesh128@gmail.com' } } ];
```

I want to send all the mail to all member email,

my expected result is:

```
var data=[ {
    ticketId: 9,
    member: {  email: ['ganeshpandi@gmail.com','braveganesh128@gmail.com'] } },
   ];
```

Is this result possible or not in foreach ?

Comment: `email: 'ganeshpandiyan@ifelsetech.com','braveganesh127@gmail.com'` -> What is the DS here?

Comment: Email is not valid, you should use array like email:['a@a.com', 'b@b.com']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your array object based on the `ticketId` in a new object accumulator, then using `Object.values()` extract all the values for each key.

```js
var data = [{ id: 9, ticketId: 9, member: { id: 3, email: 'ganeshpandi@gmail.com' } }, { id: 10, ticketId: 9, member: { id: 4, email: 'braveganesh128@gmail.com'}}],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, {ticketId, member: {email}}) => {
      r[ticketId] = r[ticketId] || {ticketId, member:{email: []}};
      r[ticketId].member.email.push(email);
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

By writing and using an implementation of a generic [`Lookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292716(v=vs.110).aspx) in JavaScript, you can simplify the logic in the `Array#reduce()` method and then map the key/value pairs of the lookup into each group of emails.

```js
const data = [{ id: 9, ticketId: 9, member: { id: 3, email: 'ganeshpandi@gmail.com' } }, { id: 10, ticketId: 9, member: { id: 4, email: 'braveganesh128@gmail.com' } }]
const lookup = data.reduce(
  (lookup, { ticketId, member: { email } }) => lookup.add(ticketId, email),
  new Lookup()
)
const result = [...lookup].map(
  ([ticketId, emails]) => ({ ticketId, member: [...emails] })
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/patrickroberts/4e6344a710569e4b7d280edc5684188d/raw/2aee1a65bfdbd7873bfacfe7ea3b5ef9a7f355f2/lookup.js"></script>
```